# Adding points to input point features option using spline method in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel

I want to interpolate raster surface from points. I have excel file consisting of latitude, longitude and values( which I want to interpolate).

How do I add these point values in input point feature to extract the desired result?

[image: excel file, first column is for latitude, 2nd for longitude and third are the point values which I want to interpolate]

Can I directly add points from excel sheet?

Answer (score 2):

I think the part that's missing is *filling in the blanks* between points, for this you can use triangulation, which is in the realms of 3d analyst extension for which you will need a valid license:

1. Import your Excel to points using [make XY Event layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006z000000) and save as
   shapefile or file geodatabase feature class.
2. [Create a new file geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000pw000000) and [feature dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000pv000000) with the same spatial reference as your input points.
3. Import your points into the feature dataset ([Copy features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000), [feature class to feature class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000) etc.).
4. [Create a Terrain](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000001n000000) with the points - this will triangulate the gaps between points.
5. If you want a raster surface then [export your terrain to raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000002t000000).

If you don't have an Esri 3d analyst license don't give up all hope, there are methods in QGIS that can triangulate a DEM from point elevations but are significantly more involved than the Esri process.

Answer (score 0):

You do want to add your points using **Add XY Data** as suggested (or the "as event theme" option). You shouldn't need to jump through hoops to create a Spline Interpolation. If you have Spatial Analyst, you can use the Spline tool directly after creating your point feature class from your spreadsheet of points with values.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to save the excel file in **CSV** format then it can be added to GIS. From the GIS you have to convert the file to layer using **Add XY Data** tool. then you can use the layer as input to interpolate raster.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/understanding-how-to-use-microsoft-excel-files-in-arcgis.htm) - "*You can open Microsoft Office Excel tables directly in ArcGIS and work with them like other tabular data sources.*"

Comment: Excel files can be opened, but csv is the standard way of adding data to gis. some features of Excel are not compatible in gis.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer received such harsh treatment. It is brief and converting to csv sounds a little bit old school since Excel does what is intended much of the time. It (Excel) does however have its own ideas about data types sometimes which may cause problems whereas csv may be more reliable.